# Drawing line with Touch iOS Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skshapenode, cgpathref

Im using the following code to draw lines in my sprite kit scene but nothing shows up. But the node counts goes up. Can anyone see what could be the problem. Ive been fighting with this code forever

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);

    lineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
    //lineNode.lineWidth = 2;
    [self addChild:lineNode];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

  //  lineNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:pathToDraw];
  //  lineNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
  //  lineNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = lines;
  //  lineNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
  //  lineNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = blueParticles | redParticles| yellowParticles;

    CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
}
```

**Edit------ Code works when background node removed..How can I set up my background node so that I can daw overtop? Thanks**

```
SKSpriteNode *background;

        if(screenHeight == 480){
            background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"iPhone4BG.png"];
        }
        if(screenHeight == 568){
            background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"iPhone5BG.png"];
        }
        if(screenHeight == 667){
            background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"iPhone6BG.png"];
        }
        if(screenHeight == 736){
            background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"iPhone6PlusBG.png"];
        }

        background.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
        background.size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);

       // [self addChild:background];
```

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553245/poor-performance-with-skshapenode-in-sprite-kit/24557658#24557658

Comment: doesn't explain why the line is not showing though? @prototypical

Comment: Added an answer. But I think both current answers, will experience the issue defined in the link. So if you are going to be drawing long lines, you should just go there and skip this approach. imo

Comment: are you testing using a simulator or actual device? @prototypical

Comment: I tested on an iPad mini.

Comment: Set the zPosition of lineNode to a value greater than the zPosition of the background node. The default value is zero.

Comment: That worked fantastic! Everything works great now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE** Core issue was Simulator not rendering a path that isn't closed. On the device the issue doesn't exist. Also a background element was involved that the original poster didn't mention and wasn't represented in code. This answer will solve the issue on the simulator.

To fix your problem, modify your code as follows :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);
    // add this line to fix your issue
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;

}
```

The core issue is that when it goes to render the path, it doesn't have a complete path. Your current approach is to be constantly modifying the path on each touchMove.

The way you close a sub path is :

```
CGPathCloseSubpath(pathToDraw);
```

However I chose to just use `CGPathMoveToPoint` each time you added a segment to the path.

From CGPath reference for `CGPathMoveToPoint` :

***This function ends the subpath already in progress (if any) and starts a new subpath, initializing the starting point and the current point to the specified location (x,y) after an optional transformation.***

I am closing the current subpath before it gets rendered, and also setting the start location for the next segment.

However, you are going to run into major issues with performance as defined in the link in the the comments if you are going to be drawing a long line or many lines.  Draw a really long line, and you will see what I mean. With minimal line drawing, you might get away with the current approach.

Sadly, drawing of this nature with `SKShapeNode` is not as optimized as it should be.

Comment: this does not work for me.. what could be the problem? I still continue to have the same problem node count goes up but no visible line to be seen

Comment: Works fine for me, I just copied your code into a empty project, added the iVars and one line and it works just fine? Perhaps your ViewController is set up incorrectly ? You can github the project if you want an I can look, but this definitely works and the problem exists outside this code above.

Comment: I figured out the problem its the background node I'm adding. Ill add the code above to show you what how I do it. Am I not allowed to draw over nodes? Whats the work around? @prototypical

Comment: If you have a layering problem, set your zPosition accordingly.

Comment: Hi @prototypical I could use help with one more question.. Im adding a physical body to this line after( as you can see in the code commented out). What happens with my original code the line doesn't show but the physical body shape is correct. I know this when objects are interacting with this line. But with your code modification you see the line but the physical body shape is incorrect it takes the shape of the first place you touched ignoring the rest of the line. I know its taking the point of where we closed the subpath but how can I fix this issue.

Comment: New question. Not good to go about answering questions in the comments as answers get hidden.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088815/adding-physical-body-to-shapes-drawn-with-cgmutablepathref

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to implement. It draws a temporary line (white) as you move your finger and draws a final line (red) when you lift your finger. You will need to declare a CGPoint instance variable named startingPoint and delete the CGMutablePathRef ivar named pathToDraw. The code can be modified to draw multiple, connected line segments as well.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    startingPoint = positionInScene;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // Remove temporary line if it exist
    [lineNode removeFromParent];

    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);

    lineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    //CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
    lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    lineNode.lineWidth = 1;
    [self addChild:lineNode];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // Remove temporary line
    [lineNode removeFromParent];

    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);

    SKShapeNode *finalLineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    finalLineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    //CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
    finalLineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
    finalLineNode.lineWidth = 1;
    [self addChild:finalLineNode];
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me.. what could be the problem? I still continue to have the same problem node count goes up but no visible line to be seen

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: it runs fine just no line is drawn when you swipe with your finger..node count goes up though when touches end

Comment: xCode 6.1 since im working with a lot of particle files and 6.0 crashes when you open them

Comment: i run in 6.0.1 just to test and still same problem

Comment: Try running it on a device. The simulator has issues drawing shape nodes.

Comment: Try creating a new project, copy my code into it, and add the ivars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62001/discussion-between-mediyum-and-0x141e).

Comment: Did you want to draw lines as the title of your question suggested or draw freehand as your code indicated?

Comment: sorry i wanted free hand i can see how i made that confusing I apologize