# How to solve poor CGPath performance? [Curve Fever clone in iOS 8 / SpriteKit]

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

**UPDATE**

More info here: [Poor performance with SKShapeNode in Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553245/poor-performance-with-skshapenode-in-sprite-kit)

I'm learning the new Swift language. To challenge myself, I'm trying to build a Curve Fever clone with SpriteKit on iOS 8. I'm using CGPath to draw a path behind the player (a circle).

```
var linePath : CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
var line : SKShapedNode!

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

     // Adjust player's location on the field based on touches left or right
     ...

     // Get the previous and current point
     var previousPoint : CGPoint = ...
     var currentPoint : CGPoint = ...

     // Add new line (from previous to current point) to the existing path
     CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, nil, previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y)
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, nil, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)

     // Redraw line
     line.removeFromParent()
     line.path = linePath // Update path
     self.addChild(line)
}
```

This works perfectly. However... After about 10 seconds the FPS goes rapidly from 60 FPS to 9 FPS. I also noticed that the memory usage is about 100 MB and more. This is not normal for a simple game that draws a moving circle and a path. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Removing and re-adding the SKShapeNode is superfluous and adversely affects performance:

```
 line.removeFromParent()
 line.path = linePath // Update path
 self.addChild(line)
```

This should suffice:

```
 line.path = linePath // Update path
```

Also worth noting is that you ought to release the path when you're done using it via `CGPathRelease(linePath)`.

Also note that if you're testing on the Simulator the performance will quickly drop because it uses a [software renderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rendering).

Comment: currently CGPathRelease is unavailable due to automatic memory management.