# Drawing Trail Lines for SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a custom LineBall class as shown below:

```
@implementation LineBall

-(instancetype) init {

    self = [super initWithImageNamed:LINE_BALL_IMAGE];

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width/2];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryLineBall;

    self.name = @"lineBall";

    self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    self.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
    self.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
    self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    return self;
}
```

Later on I add this to the GameScene and it works as expected. The problem is that now I want to draw lines wherever the LineBall travels. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you considered attaching a particle emitter to your ball?

Comment: Yes but I don't really want a particle emitter. I actually want to draw a line which other bodies can collide against.

Comment: You mean something like the Tron light cycle?

Comment: I don't know what is that? Basically I want to draw a path where ever the sprite moves.

Comment: Obviously you need a start and end point to draw a line. So in your case the only solution is probably to draw either small squares, rectangles or circles which would make up a line as your ball moves.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to draw a trail behind a moving ball.

In the `didSimulatePhysics` method:

1. Store the ball's positions over time in a mutable array. Insert at index = 0.
2. Remove the oldest (last) array element if the number of elements exceeds the max trail size
3. Create a mutable `CGPath` by looping over the elements of the array using `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to connect each point
4. Remove the old trail from the scene if it exist
5. Create the ball's trail by creating an `SKShapeNode` from the path using `shapeNodeWithPath`
6. Add the `SKShapeNode` to the scene

Comment: Be careful with this approach. SKShapeNodes are _huge_ resource hogs. A way more elegant approach would be to take a look at SKEmitterNode.

Comment: @ThomasJohannesmeyer you may be right but that's counter-intuitive given the complexity of a shape node compared to an emitter node.

Comment: But the little bit of extra work is worth it, because SKShapeNode has a huge performance impact. Especially if you use them with customised paths.

http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553245/poor-performance-with-skshapenode-in-sprite-kit


 (I did not vote this answer down by the way.)

Comment: Also: IF you end up using lots of SKShapeNodes (sometimes you just have to), make sure you recycle them using a pool.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514706/create-endless-cgpath-without-framedrops/30717729#30717729

Comment: You’re welcome. Converting them to SKSpriteNodes is another good way to handle performance. You could also create a local pool where you put your old ShapeNodes and reuse them. That’s what I ended up with. It does not scale as well as your conversion to SpriteNode though. I just use a lot of ShapeNodes, but no more than 100 at a time.