# How to avoid FPS drop when drawing lines in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, frame-rate, skshapenode

My current project contains a gravity simulator where sprites move in accordance with the forces they experience in the game scene.

One of my features involve allowing moving sprites to draw a line behind them so you can see what paths they take.

Shown here:

[image]

However, as the Sprite continues it's movements around the screen, the FPS begins to dive. This can be seen in this second image where some time has passed since the sprite first started its movement.

[image]

When researching, I found other people had posted with similar problems:

[Multiple skshapenode in one draw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807545/multiple-skshapenode-in-one-draw/20810026#20810026)

However, in the question above, the answer's poster detailed that it (The answer) was meant for a **static image**, which isn't something I want, because this line will change in real time depending on what influences the sprites path, this was reflected when I tried implementing a function to add a new Line to the old one which didn't work. That [Code here](http://pastebin.com/6gUsETis)

I'm asking if anyone can assist me in finding a way to properly stop this constant FPS drop that comes from all the draw operations. My current draw code consists of two Functions.

```
-(void)updateDrawPath:(CGPoint)a B:(CGPoint)b
{
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(_lineToDraw, NULL, b.x, b.y);
    _lineNode.path = _lineToDraw;
}

-(void)traceObject:(SKPlanetNode *)p
{
    _lineToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint((_lineToDraw), NULL, p.position.x, p.position.y);
    _lineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    _lineNode.path = _lineToDraw;
    _lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    _lineNode.antialiased = YES;
    _lineNode.lineWidth = 3;
    [self addChild:_lineNode];
}
```

- **updateDrawPath:** *Draws line to latest position of Sprite.*
- **traceObject:** *Takes SKPlanetNode (Subclass of SKSpriteNode), and sets it up to have a line drawn after it.*

If anyone can suggest a way to do this and also reduce the terrible overhead I keep accumulating, it would be fantastic!

Comment: drawing sprites gets to be n^2 if they are related to each other... try drawing your line as a bezier curve or bitmap and composite it...

Comment: I found a solution in answering this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553245/poor-performance-with-skshapenode-in-sprite-kit/24557658#24557658  -- It was in relation to drawing with touch, but the solution is directly applicable to your current issue.

Comment: @prototypical It's your solution! Also ". If you set showsDrawCount on your SKView instance, you will see what I mean." I don't get an extremely high draw count but this problem is still visible

Comment: that's what I said, I found a solution in answering that question.

Comment: It's the "caching" element of my answer you need to take note of. A SKShapeNode is NOT efficient when you have all those segments and gets even worse as you continue to draw.

Comment: @prototypical My bad, should I use the moving sprites as canvas's (Number 3 in your list)?

Comment: The canvas is what you are drawing on. Each time your sprite moves, draw a line from it's old position to the new. Every so often, you cache via flattening and recycling those shape nodes you are drawing with.

Comment: @prototypical Sorry to bug you, but I've tried implementing your solution and I'm having trouble with the cacheSegments method (Marked in file)
http://pastebin.com/uJK1pRBS

Comment: I'd have to know the problem you are having. As I said in the answer, it's not all inclusive code, but was an example of the core concepts.  "not working" is pretty vague :) error message ?

Comment: @prototypical Found the problem, wasn't initializing something I needed. No visible lines yet though.

Comment: @prototypical Thanks for the help! Lines aren't staying on screen but I'll just try again tomorrow.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score -1):

A couple suggestions:

- Consider that SKShapeNode is more or less just a tool for debug drawing mostly, due to the fact that it doesn't draw in batches it's really not suitable to make a game around that or to use it extensively (both many shapes as well as few but complex shapes).
- You could draw lines using a custom shader which will likely be faster and more elegant solution, though of course you may have to learn how to write shader programs first.
- Be sure to measure performance only on a device, never the simulator.

Comment: Custom shaders not supported in iOS7, which happens to be what I'm working with. I'll have no choice but to ditch Spritekit or find some alternative to SKShapeNode. . , unless someone can suggest a workaround. Sigh . .

Comment: If you just started you'll certainly get more freedom to draw your own stuff with SpriteBuilder + Cocos2D-Swift. I think the CCRenderer even has a built-in method to draw lines.